# NanoServer WinRM HTTPS

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2016, winrm

Trying to configure nanoserver for WinRM Remote HTTPS access and all the tutorials I have been able to find use the WinRM command and I cannot figure out how to configure it any other way. Does anyone have any advice on configuring nanoserver for WinRM HTTPS acccss?

Comment: WinRM command is unavailable on nanoserver

Answer (score 0):

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/get-started/manage-nano-server

Winrm is available for Nano, but not via standard https, the ports used are 5985, 5986.  Use winrs to run remote commands.

Comment: @ihatenanoserver The way to say thanks for any answer you've found useful on the site to vote that answer up.  If this answer answers your question, please accept this answer.  Welcome to Serverfault.